# Sorting MySQL date that uses day/month/year format

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working with some real estate listing data where the **MLS** decided to use *day/month/year format* for their listing dates.

I want to be able to do a query that sorts by date listed. If i use the *ORDER BY clause* it won't work because the day is the first number and it basically orders them all by day, regardless of year, month, etc.

**For Example:-** 02/12/2015 (december 12, 2015) would come before 05/01/2015 (january 5, 2015). The only solution I can think of is to go through each entry and re-arrange the date format.

But before I do that, is there a way to do an sql query using the *ORDER BY clause* on the current *day/month/year format*?

Comment: Have you tried using MySQL's [`STR_TO_DATE(str,format)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) - `ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(yourDate, '%d/%m/%Y')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply convert the strings to a date first:

```
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(yourdatefield, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Be aware, this query will not use indexes, and on large databases, performance will suffer. I recommend (If you're looking for speed), that you reformat this field in the database, and update the code affected.

```
UPDATE table
SET yourdatefield = STR_TO_DATE(yourdatefield, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Then, make sure the front end displays things properly. You can use the [date format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function to format outgoing dates into the format you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-',day,month,year), '%d/%m/%Y')`

Comment: If they're in separate fields, he can just simply do: `ORDER BY \`year\`, \`month\`, \`day\`` and be able to utilize indexes on the database.

Comment: I thought so, but was not sure, write it as an answer